# How to use NSBrowserDelegate methods to represent data tree

Tags: macos, nsbrowser

I am trying to represent a JSON dictionary in an `NSBrowser` on OS X 10.11. I have a dictionary which contains members of either string values, arrays of string values, or dictionaries of the same.

At `func rootItemForBrowser(browser: NSBrowser) -> AnyObject?` I provide my dictionary.

At `func browser(browser: NSBrowser, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int` I return the count of objects in either a child array or dictionary.

I am getting confused with how to use `func browser(browser: NSBrowser, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject`. The return value here ends up being a string value of one of the members, which is a key to more data. But when I then select this child, I just have a parent string to work from. I need the entire path of what the user has chosen so far to actually achieve traversal of the dictionary.

I've tried looking at the `path()` method of `NSBrowser` but that causes an infinite loop in these delegate methods. I look at apps like Finder and am curious as to how they achieve path as I want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming to the conclusion that using a dictionary on its own with the browser delegate methods wasn't getting me anywhere. What worked for me, and what I recommend for others, is to create an object which represents the dictionary that can be passed into the browser.

For example:

```
class DictionaryItem {
    let name: String
    var children: [DictionaryItem]? 
    var rawData: AnyObject?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Traverse the dictionary and add these objects to an array which the browser will use as its data source.